# Mac App Store, install to dock instead of launchpad

Tags: mac-app-store, launchpad

I am running OSX Lion, and like most people I have talked to, I believe launchpad is a bloated, useless tool. I hate that when I install a piece of software from the Mac App Store, it goes into launchpad (instead of to the dock as it did in SL), because this forces me to interact with launchpad at least to some extent.

Does anybody know if there's a way I can get the Mac App Store to behave in the way it did before Lion (place newly installed apps on the dock instead of launchpad)? I assume it'd be some sort of defaults write command or something.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you about launchpad being useless (although I don't know about bloated). There's a very simple alternative that was used before Lion: just drag your applications folder to the dock. Put it next the documents/downloads icons which should already be there. Stacks are a very useful and convenient feature of the dock, and they pretty much render launchpad useless.

I wouldn't recommend putting every app you download straight onto the dock, as it will get messy and this defeats the purpose of the dock in the first place. Most likely there are about 5-15 apps you use very frequently. Put those on the dock for one-click access. Then click the applications icon on your dock (after you put it there of course) to access all other apps. This is probably the best way to do it.

Comment: i meant bloated in that its terrible to arrange, and it isnt smart enough to not display duplicates when you have symlinks/shortcuts to apps in one of the folders it indexes. yeah i know my dock is super organized but when i get a new app, im going to launch it, why make me deal with launchpad or spotlight or quicksilver or finder to launch it when it could be right there?

Comment: @finiteloop Well I though you meant bloated as in it's used for too many functions. But yes, I agree with you there. And if you have your applications folder on your stack, you can access all of your installed apps just like launchpad, but in a much less intrusive way.

Comment: No I use quicksilver as a launcher. I just don't like that I have to deal with launch center when I install new software.